# How do I get a largely HTML site generated from a rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to create a Rails 4 app, where some data is entered into the db via a form and when it is published, any changes on the site are compiled and the entire consumer facing site is just a bunch of flat HTML files.

That way, on each request there isn't a db request done and just a simple HTML file is sent.

This is similar to the way Octopress operates, where you write a blog post locally and when you do a deploy it basically compiles the entire site into a large set of connected HTML files that are then pushed to your host(gh-pages for instance).

Is there a way to use extensive caching or something similar to get the same effect in Rails 4 or should I go about it another way in Rails or should I just try to customize Octopress for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at page caching, it has been moved from Rails to a separate gem

https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching

It saves the generated HTML files to a specified directory which you should be able to deploy separately from the rest of the application.

Comment: Hrmm...so you are suggesting that once the cache creates the HTML, I use that to deploy instead? I would have to do some complex routing right?

Comment: I haven't done it but the doc says: _Page caching works by configuring a web server to first check for the existence of files on disk, and to serve them directly when found._ So the routing should be fine in the templates. You would have to setup up your server to look for the files correctly, but this could probably be done even via `htaccess`.

Comment: Interesting....so that's one potential solution. Hoping there is another way though.